# Laravel Post Request Problem on different network

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request

My sites every post request is working in any Network. But, for any specific network(a military army network), post requests forms are getting problem. It's getting hit as normal URL, Not post request

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Screenshots
[image]

Here, everything is ok on my server and my network. **Problem on a specific network**. Please help someone.

Comment: Please check your route file and make sure that your using the right route  post::route('', '');

Comment: If I don't use that it will not work in any computer, right ! I've done everything correct, I know that. Problem is on different network, only get this error on that network.

Answer (score 0):

May be they have blocked POST requests due to security reasons.